# react-native-push-notification doesn't work on ios DEVICE

Tags: ios, react-native, notifications, device, simulator

I'm using `react-native-push-notification`, but I have a problem.
With `IOS simulator` or `android emulator`, Everything works well.
But with `real iphone device`, push notification doesn't work. (on release mode or on debug mode, both are not worked.

## Here is my setting.

[Link binary with Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pplE9.png)

[Set Search Header Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch68g.png)

I check `Capabilities`/`Background Modes`/`Remote notification` on XCODE

And PushNotification.configure

```
import React from 'react';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

import {
    Auth
} from '../config/router';
import './ReactotronConfig';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.PushConfigure();
    }
    PushConfigure() {
        PushNotification.configure({
            onNotification: (notification) => {
                console.log('NOTIFICATION:', JSON.stringify(notification));
            },
            permissions: {
                alert: true,
                badge: true,
                sound: true,
            },
            popInitialNotification: true,
            requestPermissions: true,
        });
    }
    render() {
        return <Auth />;
    }
}
```

## And when I have to push notification

```
    const date = new Date(Date.now());
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
        title: '메세지가 도착 했습니다.',
        message: `${data.user._id}: ${data.text}`,
        date,
        actions: 'Yes',
    });
```

As I said before, notification works well on all `simulator` (Xcode IOS, android).
But I don't know why notification doesn't work on `real IOS device`.

If you want more environment or settings on my project, please comment.

## Update -

I didn't register on `Apple Developer Program`.
Is that reason why I can't use notification on real IOS device?

Comment: Did app ask for the notification permission on first run on the real device?

Comment: Please check app ask notification permission and also check the certificate of push notification is perfect or not

Comment: @DinithMinura yes. permission pop up occurred.

Comment: @NisargThakkar I checked remote notification in CAPABILITIES in XCODE, and the first time the app was run, the permission pop up appeared. Anything else to check?

Comment: I didn't register on Apple Developer Program. Is that reason why I can't use notification on real IOS device?

Comment: Yes, you must have a certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think push notification is not work in iOS simulator so you need to check this in real a device and also check the certificate for push notification is proper while making a release build.

Please also check you get proper device token on `onRegister` function

```
PushNotification.configure({
           onRegister: function (token) {
                console.log((token);
            },
            onNotification: (notification) => {
                console.log('NOTIFICATION:', JSON.stringify(notification));
            },
            permissions: {
                alert: true,
                badge: true,
                sound: true,
            },
            popInitialNotification: true,
            requestPermissions: true,
        });
```

Plese make sure In settings push notification is enabled for your app

Comment: Is there any way to pop up notification locally without connection to any server like firebase, APN ..?

Comment: Yes, there is a way please follow the link. this will help you for local notification  https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification and https://medium.com/differential/how-to-setup-push-notifications-in-react-native-ios-android-30ea0131355e

Comment: I followed them at first, but the notification doesn't work on real IOS devices.

Comment: Any solution for this? I get the prompt to allow user notifications on my real device and I am enrolled in the apple dev program but I do not see the register token console log in the terminal...

Answer (score 2):

Since [Xcode 11.4](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes) - IOS Simulator should support Push Notification as well